# DIVs anchored to top and bottom of parent div

Tags: css, layout, html

This is probably a very dummy question, don't throw your shoes at me :)

Consider having HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="body">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want 'header' and 'footer' to be anchored to the parent's top and bottom respectively, and 'body' to grow easily to fit all available space.
What would the CSS look like to achieve this?

EDIT: Maybe I'm saying this wrong (i'm not exactly a web developer :) ), but what I need is to have some part of a div always attached to its bottom. So when div grows this part (which might have a fixed size) would go lower with the div's lower end. But all this doesn't mean attaching a div to the bottom of browser's window.

Comment: do you want the header and footer to be visible all of the time? like on this page http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: no, not necessarily. this is more meant for small things, not for the whole page layout. so inner divs should be at the top and bottom of their container, not the browser window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you require some really basic css.

```
body { background: black; }
.container { width: 960px; }
.header { height: 100px; background: #ddd; }
.content { padding: 10px; }
.footer { height: 100px; background: #ddd; }
```

Your div's are not floated, so will stack on top of each other like pancakes.

If you want the footer to be "sticky", see here for a solution...
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[**Example page - footer sticks to bottom**](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/FyluI)

this will have the content right 

between the footer and the header.

no overlapping.

### HTML

```
<header>HEADER</header>
<article>
  <p>some content here (might be very long)</p>
</article>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

### CSS

```
html{ height:100%; }
body{ min-height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative; }
body:after{ 
  content:''; 
  display:block; 
  height:100px; // compensate Footer's height
} 

header{ height:50px; }

footer{ 
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100px; // height of your Footer (unfortunately it must be defined)
}
```

Comment: This works only when the contents are shorter than the available space. What if I have more contents that cannot fit in the available space between header and footer. I want a scrollbar to appear with the contents `<div>` while header and footer stick to the top and bottom of the window. How do I do that?

Comment: well I wrote that answer 4 years ago. I will update it now actually.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't appear to work. As soon as the contents become longer than the available space, it pushes footer out of the screen instead of creating a scrollable `<div>` in the center.

Comment: but it does work and it does answer the OP's question. the demo page works, you can't ignore that fact. what you are asking is the exact opposite of that is asked in the question.

Comment: Ah, you took it wrong. I was not challenging the validity of this answer. What I was saying that I tried to implement it in my situation and it didn't work, so I thought your recent edit would provide a fix for it, but it didn't.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is precisely what I ended up with, though I don't like the fact that it uses absolute positioning, but it looks like there isn't any other choice.

Comment: @dotNET - you could use `Flexbox` but it lack support in older IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  Set `position: relative` on the parent div.  Set `position: absolute` on the inner div(s) and set *both* the top and the bottom properties; don't set height.  The inner div(s) should stretch vertically with the parent, as required.  (Doesn't work in IE6 and below unfortunately).